# C# commontool DatetimePicker 1 can't add value now System.DateTime.now what's happend

Tags: c#

what's happend ? Why I can't add toolbox DatetimePicker in visual C#

```
DatetimePicker 1.value= new System.DateTime.now;
```

it's error What's happend ?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: DateTime is a static class. There is no `new` it should be DatetimePicker i.value = System.DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DateTimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) is a visual control. Before using you should add it to your form/control. You have two ways to do it. First - view [designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255(v=vs.71).aspx). Second - [programmaticaly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319266). Only after adding you can use instance of the class.

In your code - you are trying to initialize instance of DateTimePicker class with DateTime value. It's not correctly, because it's different types.

You should initialize your `DateTimePicker` like this:

```
DatetimePicker dateTimePicker1= new DateTimePicker();
```

And set value with property [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
```

BTW it's a very bad way to name your variables with only numbers. I can recommend you to read about [variables and coding conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker;
 dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Also need to add as control `Controls.Add(dateTimePicker1);`